# Shorter way to define a table of platforms

Tags: lua, lua-table, love2d

so basically i have this code, that controls my platforms (I want to create a 2d platformer game) for the game (Love2D Lua ) here's the script

```
platforms = {}
platform1 = { x = 0, y = 600, width = 279, height = 49 }
platform2 = { x = 279, y = 600, width = 279, height = 49 }
platform3 = { x = 558, y = 600, width = 279, height = 49 }
table.insert(platforms, platform1)
table.insert(platforms, platform2)
table.insert(platforms, platform3)
```

Is there any better way to control/create platforms ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your platforms have their size in common you may use something like this:

```
platforms = {
    { x = 0, y = 600 },
    { x = 279, y = 600 },
    { x = 558, y = 600 },
};
for _,v in ipairs(platforms) do
    v.width = 279;
    v.height = 49;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `platforms` as an array (which seems to be what you want):

```
platforms = {
  { x = 0, y = 600, width = 279, height = 49 },
  { x = 279, y = 600, width = 279, height = 49 },
  { x = 558, y = 600, width = 279, height = 49 },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As only the `x` value gets changed:

```
platforms = {}
for _, x in ipairs{0, 279, 558} do
    table.insert(platforms, {x = x, y = 600, width = 279, height = 49})
end
```

Comment: What if Y also will change ? and what should i type insted of '_' , or i should type this symbol?

Comment: @LostPuppy, `_` symbol means that you just ignore that variable. You don't need keys for `{0, 279, 558}` table which is `1, 2, 3`

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, to declare them you can have them in the table when it is declared.

```
platforms = {
    { x = 999, y = 999, w = 999, h = 99 },
    ...
}
```

Once you have that table established you can always add to it.

```
table.insert(platforms, { x = 111, y = 111, w = 111, h = 111 }
```

Or take away one, providing you know which index it is (How far down the list it is)

```
table = {
    { }, -- Index 1
    { }, -- Index 2
    ...
}
```

And then to take away one:

```
table.remove(platforms, 1)
```

This will remove the platform under the index 1.

To sift through the them you could use ipairs.

```
for i, v in ipairs(platforms) do
    v.y = v.y - 10 * dt -- Do something, this would slowly raise all platforms
end
```

That should be all you need, have fun!